# Python-Ubuntu Raspberry errors telegram

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I've a problem programming a `raspberry`. I'm trying to program a `Telegram` bot in `Python`, I've connected the `raspberry` with my computer with `PuTTY` and then I've upgraded `Python` to the last and then to the `3,6` version and downloaded all the `pip` i need.

Now, I've used the `nano` compilator (because with `PuTTy` i've `Linux`) and when I do the

```
python + 'nameofthefile'
```

I have this error:

```
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py:16: 
UserWarning: The soupsieve package is not installed. CSS selectors cannot be used.
  'The soupsieve package is not installed. CSS selectors cannot be used.
```

At the top of the code I have to import these stuff:

```
import request
import telepot
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I've downloaded (with `sudo pip install`): `telepot`, `time`, `request`, `bs4` and `BeautifulSoup`.

I've also downloaded `soupsieve` but the problem persists.

What can I do?

Comment: `nano` is editor, not compilator. Besides in scripting languages like Python, Perl, PHP, Ruby nobody say "compilation" because scirpt runs at once without manual compilation like in C/C++/Java.

Comment: if error shows `"not installed."` then you have to install it using `pip install ...` or `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: now I see - your problem caan be that you have to Python installed 2.7 and 3.6 - your error shows that you run 2.7 (see `python2.7` in path in error)  but probably you installed modules in 3.6 - try `python3` or `python3.6` instead of `python`. And `pip3` or `pip3.6` instead of `pip`

Comment: hello, I've reinstalled all using pip3 but when i use python 'nameofthefile.py' it says the same error and it try to take the package from the python2.7 lib and not from the 3

Comment: you have to use `python3 nameofthefile.py`

Comment: or add `shebang` like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in first line of `nameofthefile.py` and run `chmod a+x nameofthefile.py` in terminal to make it "executable" and then you can run it without `python3` - only  `nameofthefile.py` - because Linux will use information  from `shebang` to run it with `python3`